# eclipse update through proxy with jre 6.0

Tags: eclipse, proxy, java

When doing plug-in updates, I was able to get through my proxy with eclipse using jre 1.4.1.

jre 6.0 gives me the error

"Malformed reply from SOCKS server"

any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

adding

```
-Dorg.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.excludeContributors=org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient
```

to the eclipse.ini worked